# How to use nested subgraphs from graphml in igraph

Tags: python, igraph

The graphML specification provides the possibility to create graphs as child of a node element, .e.g.

```
<graphml>
  <graph id="G" edgedefault="undirected">
    <node id="n0"/>
    <node id="n1">
      <graph id="n1::" edgedefault="directed">
        <node id="n1::n0"/>
        <node id="n1::n1"/>
        <edge id="e0" source="n1::n0" target="n1::n1"/>
      </graph>
    </node>
    <edge id="e1" source="n0" target="n1"/>
    <edge id="e2" source="n1" target="n1::n0"/>
  </graph>
</graphml>
```

Is it possible to use igraph to interpret the information from these subgraph? Currently (I am using python igraph version 0.7.1) all edges after subgraph declaration are ignored, which leads to the following graph:

[image: Example Graph]

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, nested graphs are not supported by igraph.

Comment: thank you Tamás. What do you think about the effort in supporting it in igraph? Just thinking about the difference in evaluating another framework vs. adding support for nested graphs in igraph myself.

Comment: Nested graphs is probably not going to happen in igraph any time soon, sorry. (We are quite low on spare time and nested graphs would require too many changes in the underlying data model).